# Test breaks with FailureHandling set to OPTIONAL with WebUI.verifyElementPresent

Tags: automated-testing, katalon

When running the following **code** (in Katalon Studio):

```
if (WebUI.verifyElementPresent(findTestObject('Object Repository/xyz'), 
    5, FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)) {
    WebUI.click(findTestObject('xyz'))
}
```

I received the following **error** message:

```
Test Cases/abc FAILED because (of) Unable to click on object 'Object 
Repository/xyz' (Root cause: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: 
element not visible)
```

So, even though the presence of the object is optional, I get an error message. Did you have a similar case?

Comment: *the presence of the object is optional* what tells you that the presence is optional?

Comment: It tells me that it's not mandatory to handle failures

Comment: My intention with this code is: "if the element is present, click it, if not continue...". So, if the element is not present, why should I get this error message, shouldn't it just continue with code execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element seems to be present, but unreachable.

Use `verifyElementClickable(...)` instead of `verifyElementPresent(...)`

**Documentation:**

[Reference Document](https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/%5BWebUI%5D+Verify+Element+Clickable)

Answer (score 0):

Your element might be present but maybe hidden.
Use `verifyElementVisible` instead, e.g:

```
if (WebUI.verifyElementVisible(findTestObject('Object Repository/xyz'), 
    FailureHandling.OPTIONAL)) {
    WebUI.click(findTestObject('Object Repository/xyz'))
 }
```